# C++ Struct - Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++, struct

when i try to compile the following, i receive the error "Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'". Does anyone know why am i receiving this error? What am i doing wrong here?

```
struct HE_edge {
HE_vert* vert; // vertex at the end of the half-edge<br>
HE_edge* pair; // oppositely oriented half-edge<br>
HE_face* face; // the incident face<br>
HE_edge* prev; // previous half-edge around the face<br>
HE_edge* next; // next half-edge around the face<br>
};

struct HE_vert {
float x, y, z; // the vertex coordinates<br>
HE_edge* edge; // one of the half-edges emanating from the vertex<br>
};

struct HE_face {
HE_edge* edge; // one of the half-edges bordering the face<br>
};
```

Comment: You need your declarations in the opposite order. `HE_edge` tries to use `HE_vert`, which the compiler doesn't know about yet.

Comment: ho forward declaration of you types ? So HE_vert does not name a type in the definition of HE_edge. A lot of compiler tell you this now, apparently not yours.

Comment: In fact, I didn't immediately realise you have a circular dependency. Look at [forward declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/1171191).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to declare your structs in the right order :
Since HE_edge depends on HE_vert and HE_face, declare them before.

```
struct HE_vert;
struct HE_face;

struct HE_edge {
HE_vert* vert; // vertex at the end of the half-edge<br>
HE_edge* pair; // oppositely oriented half-edge<br>
HE_face* face; // the incident face<br>
HE_edge* prev; // previous half-edge around the face<br>
HE_edge* next; // next half-edge around the face<br>
};

struct HE_vert {
float x, y, z; // the vertex coordinates<br>
HE_edge* edge; // one of the half-edges emanating from the vertex<br>
};

struct HE_face {
HE_edge* edge; // one of the half-edges bordering the face<br>
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward declare `HE_vert` and `HE_face` before you use them in `HE_edge`.

```
// fwd declarations. Can use "struct" or "class" interchangeably.
struct HE_vert;
struct HE_face;

struct HE_edge { /* as before */ };
```

See [When to use forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare all the classes before you use their types to make pointers:

```
struct HE_edge;
struct HE_vert;
struct HE_face;

// your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You must *declare* identifiers before you use them. For structures this is simply done by e.g.

```
struct HE_vert;
```

Place that before the definition of `HE_edge`.

Answer (score 1):

The first declaration has no idea what `HE_vert` and `HE_face` is, to you need to tell the compiler what are those:

```
struct HE_face;
struct HE_vert;//tell compiler what are HE_vert and HE_face

struct HE_edge {
HE_vert* vert; // vertex at the end of the half-edge<br>
HE_edge* pair; // oppositely oriented half-edge<br>
HE_face* face; // the incident face<br>
HE_edge* prev; // previous half-edge around the face<br>
HE_edge* next; // next half-edge around the face<br>
};

struct HE_vert {
float x, y, z; // the vertex coordinates<br>
HE_edge* edge; // one of the half-edges emanating from the vertex<br>
};

struct HE_face {
HE_edge* edge; // one of the half-edges bordering the face<br>
};
```

Razvan.